# Javascript inclusion in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I followed step by step this tutorial to include owl-carousel in Magento 2. http://www.boolfly.com/magento-2-slider-with-owl-carousel./
The problem is that I get this error:

```
VM29879:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
```

on this script

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">// <![CDATA[
require([
    'jquery',
    'owlcarousel',
], function ($) {   
      $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
            navigation: true,
            items: 4
        });
    });
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

(somehow I cannot put everything here, but you can see the code in the article also).

Because of this error, requirejs doesn't load my script.

If I remove `type="text/x-magento-init"` I don't get the error, but still no js loaded, because it needs this type.

Does anyone had this problem or know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your requiejs-config.js file with below code,

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
            'owlcarousel': "js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel"
        },   
    shim: {
        'owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

after apply code press below command,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Thanks.

Comment: I also have this issue when I run this command `Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hairperfection/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php on line 64`, but I opened another issue for this.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do not need use "text/x-magento-init for you script. It's used only for declarative component initializing and use json format.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong,  unless I'm  creating  a section that needs to be updated via Ajax i do not need to use text/x-magento-init